# Update NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Please consider the method at the end of this question. It attempts to delete all records from a CoreData entity.

The first -outcommented- part works fine: it deletes everything from my context, and then saves the context.

The second, non-commented part doesn't seem to work:
As a test I do

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"myEntity"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Fetch request returns %lu objects", (unsigned long)[results count]);
```

When I add records, and delete all records with the method below, the amount of records only increase.

As far as I understand, it actually works, but the context is not aware of it (yet).

So, therefore, in order to get a reliable context, I should update the context with

```
[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:<#(nonnull NSDictionary *)#> intoContexts:self.managedObjectContext];
```

However, I don't have a clue what I should enter in the (nonnull NSDictionary *) part.

BTW: I only want to use the NSBatchDeleteRequest because I assume it is faster than iterating through all records.

```
- (void)deleteAllEntities:(NSString *)nameEntity
    {

        id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.managedObjectContext= [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        /*
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:nameEntity];
        [fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects)
        {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
        }

        error = nil;
        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        */


        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:nameEntity];
        NSBatchDeleteRequest *delete = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request];

        NSError *deleteError = nil;


    }
```

Comment: You do actually call `executeRequest` on the context, with the batchDeleteRequest, don't you?